# Facebook Graph API {id}/feed?limit=x - restrict to messages since a certain message id

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a small problem, I am working on an aggregation application that is collecting messages from pages in realtime.

This is working fine, but I get the same message on every call and then filter out the messages that I have already seen manually.

This means that a large amount of data is being transferred every time I make a call to the graph api.

Is there a way to limit the message as messages since this message id?

currently using the c# Facebook SDK

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.limit = _facebookMessagesToRetrieveAtATime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //Want to add a new param here to say messages since this id.

        var facebookUrl = String.Format("{0}/feed", "Page ID");
        dynamic resp = fb.Get(facebookUrl, parameters);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `since` url parameter in your calls, as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#paging

This would make it necessary that you store somewhere in your application the timestamp when you last requested the respective feed

This would yield in

```
var facebookUrl = String.Format("{0}/feed?since={last_update_timestamp}", "Page ID");
```

where `{last_update_timestamp}` is the timestamp (unixtime in seconds) of the last update.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in the end, which meant I had to change my schema to hold the last time as well as the last message id.